# Partition device missing after partitioning LV with sfdisk

Tags: linux, lvm, partition, formatting, hard-drive

I've successfully partitioned a logical volume (/dev/dm-2) using sfdisk and `fdisk -l` now reports there to be a partition /dev/dm-2p1 as desired. However, this device does not seem to exist in /dev/ and I'm unsure why/where to find it so that I can now format it using mkfs.

The output of `fdisk -l` is:

```
Disk /dev/dm-2: 20.9 GB, 20971520000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2549 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/dm-2p1               1        2549    20474811   83  Linux
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device in /dev doesn't exists because the Linux kernel isn't notified about partition table changes automaticly. You can use `partprobe` (part of Parted) to re-scan your partition table or reboot the machine to have your device nodes created.

Comment: Thanks. After running this though, there was still no /dev/dm-2p1 device. I found that I actually have to use /dev/mapper/{vgname}-{lvname}p1 to access the partition. Possibly that's a result of using an lv?